# How do you get the size of a file in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Given a path to a file on disk, what is the most idiomatic way to retrieve the file size in bytes?

```
path = "/tmp/some_file.txt"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is achieved in Elixir by utilising the builtin `stat` functions in the `File` module; here, I will talk about two: [`File.stat/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#stat/2) and [`File.stat!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#stat!/2).

Both functions return a `%File.Stat{}` struct for their "value", which we then destructure via pattern matching to pluck out the `size` field which contains the file size, in bytes. The functions only differ in how they 1) return and 2) handle exceptions (e.g file not found).

**For file size checks that throw exceptions** (`File.Error`):

```
iex(1)> %{size: size} = File.stat! path
1562
```

**For file size checks that handle exceptions gracefully and return an error tuple**:

```
iex(1)> case File.stat path do
...(1)>   {:ok, %{size: size}} -> size
...(1)>   {:error, reason} -> ... # handle error
...(1)> end
1562
```

**N.B**: There are other functions that handle slightly differently when dealing with symlinks and are worth knowing about: [`File.lstat/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#lstat/2) & [`File.lstat!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#lstat!/2).